# MySQL Order by 2nd Column without referring to column Name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables that are returned by a PHP function. This takes in the table to be returned and carries out the required transforms/SQL. However as part of this I would like to order the data by the 2nd column in the table. However, this column does not always have the same name (can be one of two names), so I would therefore like to be able to refer to it by its column number instead of by its actual name, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Order by 2 -- 2 is the second column or expression from your select
```

**Example 1**:

```
select 
       col1, 
       some_expression( col2, colM ) as `single_phrase_col_head` 
  from table_name
 order by 2 -- `single_phrase_col_head`
```

**Example 2**:

```
select 
       col1, 
       some_expression( col2, colM ) as `multi word col head` 
  from table_name
 order by 2 -- `multi word col head`
```